# How to process data in a form using php without submitting it

Tags: php, forms, process

When I enter a video ID and the length of loan and then hit button FindDetails my form will show the name of the video, it's price to hire and the total cost of hire.

This causes two problems:

1. Submitting the form wipes video ID and the length of loan. Rats!
2. I cant adjust how many days I want to borrow a video and watch
   the cost of the loan automatically adjust.

NB I include all php script as I will actually need to submit the form to write details of the reservation in a csv file. I'm not sure if this will stop a work around solution.

**PHP**:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['FindDetails'])) {
    $ID = $_POST['videoID'];
    $Days = $_POST['days'];

//Open the CSV file 
    $file_handle = fopen("video.csv", "r");
//loop until hit the last line feof)
    while (!feof($file_handle)) 
        {
//put data in each line [0],[1] etc into a variable.
        $info = fgetcsv($file_handle);
// Check its the one we want.
        if($info[0]==$_POST["videoID"])
                {
            $videoName = "$info[2]";
            $videoCost ="$info[4]";
            $costOfHire= $videoCost*$Days;
                }
            }
            fclose($file_handle);
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$ID = $_POST['videoID'];
$VideoName = $_POST['videoName'];
$VideoCost = $_POST['videoCost'];
$Days = $_POST['days'];
$Total = $_POST['total'];
$DateFrom = $_POST['date_from'];
$DateTo = $_POST['date_to'];
$StudentName = $_POST['studentName'];

   //Saving loan details
   $csv_file = 'loans.csv';
    if (is_writable($csv_file)) {
        if (!$csv_handle = fopen($csv_file,'a')) {
        // this line is for troubleshooting
        echo "<p>Cannot open file $csv_file</p>";
        exit;
        }

   $csv_item = "\"$ID\",\"$VideoName\",\"$VideoCost\",\"$Days\",\"$Total\",\"$DateFrom\",\"$DateTo\",\"$StudentName\"\n";
    if (is_writable($csv_file)) {
        if (fwrite($csv_handle, $csv_item) === FALSE) {
        //for testing
        //echo "Cannot write to file";
        exit; } 
    }
   fclose($csv_handle);
   }
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo "<p style='padding: .5em; border: 2px solid red;'>Thanks for booking the Video.  Please collect from E24 on the date ordered.</p>";
}
?>
```

HTML:

## Loans

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
Enter the Video ID below
<table id="tables" class="form" style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>Video ID</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" name="videoID" id="videoID" placeholder= "Enter A Number between 1 and 8"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="FindDetails" id="FindDetails" value="Search Video" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Video Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($videoName))?$videoName:'';?>"  name="videoName" id="videoName"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Video Rental Cost (per day)</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($videoCost))?$videoCost:'';?>" name="videoCost" id="videoCost"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Number of days</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" name="days" id="days" placeholder= "Enter the number of days you wish to borrow the video for" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total cost</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($costOfHire))?$costOfHire:'';?>" name="total" id="total"/></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: look into hidden form fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1

I assume the HTML and PHP portions presented are in the same file.

You use `<?php echo (isset($costOfHire))?$costOfHire:'';?>` for example to access variables set in the PHP code.

Why not use `<?php echo (isset($ID))?$ID:'';?>` to simply recycle the submitted video ID? Then do the same for the length of loan variable.

Part 2

Here is one way live loan cost calculation could work. The javascript will go between `<script></script>` tags in the `<head>` of the document.

```js
function updateLoanCost(loanPeriod) {
    var costDisplayEl = document.getElementById("loanCostDisplay");
    
    var dollarsPerDay = 3;
    costDisplayEl.innerText = "$" + loanPeriod * dollarsPerDay;
}
```

```html
Enter a number of days <br />
<input type = "number" id = "test" onchange = "updateLoanCost(this.value);"/>
<div id = "loanCostDisplay"></div>
```

Comment: I should also add: A less hacky solution might be to use cookies. Just in case later on you want information persist across multiple pages.

Comment: Of course!! Yes the <?php echo (isset($ID))?$ID:'';?> works for VideoID and length of loan variables. Thanks!  Just trying to figure out your second suggestion regarding java script. I want the least amount of code possible since I will also need to check if a video has been reserved by a student as well!

Comment: See my edit regarding part 2. Hope that is more helpful.